# Store the date (timestamp) of the oldest file from a directory in Linux in a variable (shell script)

Tags: linux, shell, date

I am trying to find the date of the oldest log file that's at least 10 days old underneath the `/home/` directory.

```
find /home -type f –name "*.log" –mtime +10 -ls | sort | head - n 1 >>/home/text.txt
```

Am using +10 since I need to find the date after 10 days period.

```
startDate = cut –d '_' –f20,22 text.txt to get the date.
```

But this code is not working correctly. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the output? Recall, `-mtime +10` is after `10 * 24 hour periods` with any fractional part **ignored**. You may need `9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what you want to do is use find to locate the oldest log file over 10 days old below the /home/ directory. If that is your goal, then you can use a `find` command similar to:

```
find /home -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +10 -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS %p\n" | \
sort | head -n 1 >> /home/text.txt
```

The output before the `head` command will be a list of files found sorted in ascending order as follows (shown with "*.c" pattern):

```
20140621130603.9932529560 ./fill8bit.c
20140623130713.1503117800 ./strtol2.c
20140623133243.9487796380 ./strtol1.c
20140623215536.9085778830 ./mpg.c
...
```

The head -n1 simply takes the first. That being:

```
20140621130603.9932529560 ./fill8bit.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

```
oldest=$(stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" /home/**/*.log | sort -n | head -1 | cut -f2)
```

or

```
oldest10=$(find /home/ -type f –name “*.log” –mtime +10 -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m%t%Sm" | sort -n | head -1 | cut -f2)
```

Explanation:

- `find` finds the right files
- `stat` prints the date in format "seconds TAB date"
- `sort` sorts by seconds (numerically) - lowest number (seconds) first (so it is the oldest)
- `head` get the first line (oldest)
- `cut` removes the seconds field.

if you have GNU find, you can use the `-printf` to get the "seconds TAB date" and not need to use the `xargs` and `stat` commands, e.g:

```
find arguments -printf "%T@\t%c\n" | sort -n | head -1 | cut -f2
```

Comment: Or: `oldest=$(find /home/ -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +10 -exec stat -f "%m%t%d" {} + | sort -n | head -n 1 | cut -f2)`, avoiding the need for `xargs`.

Comment: One other minor comment; the `/home/**/*.log` notation could expand into a list of files that is too big to fit in a single command's argument list.  Using the `find` command with either the `+` or with `xargs` avoids that being a problem.  The `stat` command and the `-printf` option to `find` (as well as `-print0` and `xargs -0`) are using GNU extensions over POSIX.  However, the question is tagged Linux, so that isn't a problem.